# Need assistance w/ dynamic highlighting an image-sprite navigation menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, navigation, sprite, highlighting

I have an image based menu on a wordpress site Im building that Id like to be able to dynamically highlight for each section & **more importantly highlight while each visitor is viewing a child page or post within its respective page**.

I've sorted out how to get each section to highlight just fine when viewing that parent page, however Ive run into some trouble with achieving the same effect when I choose to view a post or subpage.

Since **Im utilizing categories to filter content to specific pages** I was able to get each section to still highlight when viewing a post by using: `<?php if ( is_page('page-name') || is_category('cat-name') || in_category('cat-name')) { echo ' class="xxxx_highlight" '; } ?>` yet this also caused a few problems as well unfortunately....What happened was, as soon as there was content posted to both the BLOG & MEDIA section - both sections would highlight simultaneously which is obviously not what were going for here. Couldn't really figure out why that occurred however so I removed the `in_category()` & `is_category()`...

Ive been looking through the conditional tags section up and down for the last couple weeks with no avail as to what additional tags are at my disposal in order to achieve this with a sprite menu. What would be ideal rather then targeting "categories" would be if there were a tag to simply look for if a single.php page & subpage of a parent in the menu was in use...couldn't really find anything that worked however so Im hoping some php/wordpress guru can point in the right direction hopefully!

Here is my current markup:
**HTML MENU**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="/" id="logo"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/" id="home" <?php if ( is_front_page('events')) { echo ' class="home_highlight" '; } ?>></a><!-- HOME -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/artists" id="artists" <?php if ( is_page('artists')) { echo ' class="artists_highlight" '; } ?>></a><!-- ARTISTS -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/media" id="media" <?php if ( is_page('media')) { echo ' class="media_highlight" '; } ?>></a><!-- MEDIA -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/blog" id="blog" <?php if ( is_home('blog')) { echo ' class="blog_highlight" '; } ?>></a><!-- BLOG -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/store" id="store" <?php if ( is_page('store')) { echo ' class="store_highlight" '; } ?>></a><!-- STORE -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/contact" id="contact" <?php if ( is_page('contact')) { echo ' class="contact_highlight" '; } ?>></a><!-- CONTACT -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest to you is use echo in "ul", something like

```
<ul id="nav" class="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
..... li's and a's here
```

So via CSS you just do

```
.N #home, .M #artists, .X #media { [active styling] } /* where N is home ID, M is artists ID, X is media ID and so on */
```

So, when you are in page that gives ul class "N" you know that #home will be active. When you are in "M" you know that artists is active.

PS: You could even use a custom field like "classname" for a better menu control..

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you extrapolate on whats going on there a little for me though?...thanks

Comment: I dont see how that helps me though since class="<?php echo $post->ID; ?> generates a different unique class ID for each post. I need a way to basically just add another conditional to the li elements in the list in order for wordpress to recognize that Im visiting a child page or post of a parent so that the respective nav section stays highlighted...Maybe im missing the point of your example but I dont think this what Im looking for, thank you though.

Comment: Instead of post->ID you could use a test if it's page or subpage and then echo ID.. More about check if is subpage: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Testing_for_paginated_Pages

Comment: Thanks, I tried that earlier but gave it another go since you recommended it, but still didn't have any luck unfortunately...

I wonder if JQuery would more easily solve this issue? This would be a piece of cake if I were using wp_list_pages but since Im hard coding an image-sprite based menu that wasnt an option...It would be fantastic if wordpress simply offered a way to generate active state classes the same way wp_list_pages does without actually having to use that function. 

Not really sure where else to turn to at this point?

Comment: I realized that is_category() is looking "for" a category and in_category() is looking "inside" a category so I removed is_category() and only kept in_category() and I at least achieved the results I was after for the 3 sections that are post driven, however Im still basically stuck at square one since Im going to need to be able to highlight other sections of the site when visiting a child page. Still kinda unable to find a good solution it seems, or at least one I can sort out on my own :(

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else possibly runs into the same issue I had here, Ive finally found a solution on my own after several hours of sifting through the wordpress codex...

Turns out the answer to this problem is far easier then I would have imagined. All you need to do is take advantage of wordpresses own `<?php body_class($class); ?>` tag...Once youve coded this in, go to firebug and inspect the outputted classes that the tag generates depending on what page your at. So now at this point its very easy to use the generated classes (the page-template-xxxx class in particular) and target that class via CSS to highlight what you need in the oldschool way you would with a static site.

Hope that helps out anybody else with the same dilemma I had!

Comment: After further research it turns out that the body class does not create unique "page" classes when visiting single pages so the problem still exists after all...Its a shame Wordpress doesnt simply add more classes through the body class then it already does. The classes are really more helpful if you have a typical navigation menu without images, once you add images things become a lot more complicated it seems.